# update a value in the control

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Following is the default code in mvc, what I want is go give 'hint' a value in this function to let me known the data has changed

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "ID,categoryID,subTitle,subject,sen,image,hint")] List list)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.Entry(list).State = EntityState.Modified;
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("ListSpryList", new { id = list.categoryID });
    }
    return View(list);
}
```

I think I maybe should insert something like following, before the code "db.saveChanges()"

```
db.Engtry(list.hit).value="changed";
```

it is obvious wrong but something like this.

Comment: Don't use Entity Framework entity objects as ViewModels.

Comment: In an EF context, updating a value simply done by a select query to target data and assign update value to its result(s), then use `db.SaveChanges()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh, sorry everyone, it is a quite stupid question, only need to insert a sinple code

```
list.sen = "changed";
```

before

```
db.SaveChanges();
```

then I got what I want

Sorry everyone for waste your time.